# Automate Finding non-nan values and their corresponding index points

Tags: python, arrays, indexing

Automate finding the values at varying points based on the index numbers that correspond to legitimate values (not NaNs) as there will be many NaNs throughout the data based on the function that I placed on the initial data.

I have a DataFrame (named 'future') where I picked out specific points of relative min/max throughout (743 initial rows) and was able place the index spot of these min/max into arrays and add them to the 'graph' dataframe ('closemin', 'closemax', 'rsimin', 'rsimax')The values of the arrays consist of the INDEX POINTS of these min/max values within their respective columns in the 'graph' DataFrame.

I am attempting to find the slope between the relative close min/max values and then compare that to the slope of the RSIE14 at the same index points. I can find the index points easily but do not have a method to automate the process - which I need for other datasets, as the NaN values in between these relative min/max points will change often. 
For example, in the picture below there are relative 'closemin' at index numbers 351 and 340. I would like to automate getting those index points and then simultaneously get the same index points (351 and 340) for the RSIE14 data so that I can automate finding the slope of the two.
[image: Pic showing dataframe and array outputs]

Answer (score 1):

As you are looping through those rows you need to refer to a common index that applies to both Dataframes. In my example here I have two dataframes with different data but refer to the same index. Let's say one dataframe refers to close data and the other to closemin data.

This is how it could work:

```
import pandas as pd
import random

my_randoms = [random.sample(range(100), 10), random.sample(range(100), 10)]
my_other_randoms = [random.sample(range(100), 10), random.sample(range(100), 10)]

first_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(my_randoms).T
second_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(my_other_randoms).T

print(first_dataframe)
print("----")
print(second_dataframe)
print("----")

for index, row in first_dataframe.iterrows():
    print(f"Index of current row: {index} \n"
          f"Values of current row: {row.values}\n"
          f"Values on same row other DF: {second_dataframe.iloc[index].values}\n"
          f"----")
```

With output:

```
    0   1
0  90  61
1  99  88
2  15  56
3  17  37
4  95  93
5  23  43
6  68  14
7   7   9
8  97   2
9  53  91
----
    0   1
0   6  88
1  21  51
2   2  50
3  38  40
4  11  67
5  57  80
6   9  41
7  88  47
8  41  72
9  42  52
----
Index of current row: 0 
Values of current row: [90 61]
Values on same row other DF: [ 6 88]
----
Index of current row: 1 
Values of current row: [99 88]
Values on same row other DF: [21 51]
----
Index of current row: 2 
Values of current row: [15 56]
Values on same row other DF: [ 2 50]
----
Index of current row: 3 
Values of current row: [17 37]
Values on same row other DF: [38 40]
----
Index of current row: 4 
Values of current row: [95 93]
Values on same row other DF: [11 67]
----
Index of current row: 5 
Values of current row: [23 43]
Values on same row other DF: [57 80]
----
Index of current row: 6 
Values of current row: [68 14]
Values on same row other DF: [ 9 41]
----
Index of current row: 7 
Values of current row: [7 9]
Values on same row other DF: [88 47]
----
Index of current row: 8 
Values of current row: [97  2]
Values on same row other DF: [41 72]
----
Index of current row: 9 
Values of current row: [53 91]
Values on same row other DF: [42 52]
----
```

Comment: So the as I loop through the rows, and find the min/max points, they are very sparse (a lot of NaN) and will change for every data set that I apply this loop. Would there be anyway to isolate the min/max values that correspond to the index points that are given with this forloop, and then apply simple math to the. For example, when I run this:
Index in 'futures DF:  Value of 'columns
24                             123.15
127                           163.45
179                           176.98

And I want to take the difference based on value of columns. Hope that made sense.

Comment: Could you edit your question with an example of the datasets and the data you want to extract?

Comment: I added a new picture and a refined explanation. Thank you for your time and effort!